# Swift In App Purchase no Alert pops up

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I tried to implement In-App purchases to my App. I followed the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwPFtwDJ7tc&index=12&list=WL but when I tried to run it no Alert pops up if I press the button. The Sample project works perfectly fine but after entering my own Purchases nothing works.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyStoreKit
import StoreKit

var sharedSecret = "919a706ee42143df8571a316f14531c8"

enum RegisteredPurchase : String {
case Dolla10 = "10Dolla"
case RemoveAds = "RemoveAds"
case autoRenewable = "autoRenewable"
}



class NetworkActivityIndicatorManager : NSObject {

private static var loadingCount = 0

class func NetworkOperationStarted() {
    if loadingCount == 0 {

        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }
    loadingCount += 1
}
class func networkOperationFinished(){
    if loadingCount > 0 {
        loadingCount -= 1

    }

    if loadingCount == 0 {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

    }
}
}

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var MoneyLbl: UILabel!

var Money = Int()

let bundleID = "com.KonradLoecher.inAppPurchase"

var Dolla10 = RegisteredPurchase.Dolla10
var RemoveAds = RegisteredPurchase.RemoveAds

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.MoneyLbl.text = "\(self.Money)"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func Consumable1(_ sender: Any) {
    purchase(purchase: Dolla10)
}

@IBAction func Consumable2(_ sender: Any) {
    purchase(purchase: RemoveAds)
}

@IBAction func Renewable(_ sender: Any) {

}

@IBAction func NonRenewable(_ sender: Any) {
}



func getInfo(purchase : RegisteredPurchase) {
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo([bundleID + "." + purchase.rawValue], completion: {
        result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()

        self.showAlert(alert: self.alertForProductRetrievalInfo(result: result))


    })
}

func purchase(purchase : RegisteredPurchase) {
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(bundleID + "." + purchase.rawValue, completion: {
        result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()

        if case .success(let product) = result {

            if product.productId == self.bundleID + "." + "10Dolla"{

                self.Money += 10
                self.MoneyLbl.text = "\(self.Money)"

            }
            if product.productId == self.bundleID + "." + "RemoveAds" {

                self.Money += 100
                 self.MoneyLbl.text = "\(self.Money)"
            }

            if product.needsFinishTransaction {
                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(product.transaction)
            }
            self.showAlert(alert: self.alertForPurchaseResult(result: result))
        }


    })

}
func restorePurchases() {
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.restorePurchases(atomically: true, completion: {
        result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()

        for a product in a result.restoredProducts {
            if product.needsFinishTransaction {
                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(product.transaction)
            }
        }

        self.showAlert(alert: self.alertForRestorePurchases(result: result))

    })
}
func verifyReceipt() {
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt(password: sharedSecret, completion: {
        result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()

        self.showAlert(alert: self.alertForVerifyReceipt(result: result))

        if case .error(let error) = result {
            if case .noReceiptData = error {

                self.refreshReceipt()

            }
        }

    })

}
func verifyPurcahse(product : RegisteredPurchase) {
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt(password: sharedSecret, completion: {
        result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()

        switch result{
        case .success(let receipt):

            let productID = self.bundleID + "." + product.rawValue

            if product == .autoRenewable {
                let purchaseResult = SwiftyStoreKit.verifySubscription(productId: productID, inReceipt: receipt, validUntil: Date())
                self.showAlert(alert: self.alertForVerifySubscription(result: purchaseResult))

            }
            else {
                let purchaseResult = SwiftyStoreKit.verifyPurchase(productId: productID, inReceipt: receipt)
                self.showAlert(alert: self.alertForVerifyPurchase(result: purchaseResult))

            }
        case .error(let error):
            self.showAlert(alert: self.alertForVerifyReceipt(result: result))
            if case .noReceiptData = error {
                self.refreshReceipt()

            }

        }


    })

}
func refreshReceipt() {
    SwiftyStoreKit.refreshReceipt(completion: {
        result in

        self.showAlert(alert: self.alertForRefreshRecepit(result: result))

    })

}

}

extension ViewController {

func alertWithTitle(title : String, message : String) -> UIAlertController {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    return alert

}
func showAlert(alert : UIAlertController) {
    guard let _ = self.presentedViewController else {
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

}
func alertForProductRetrievalInfo(result : RetrieveResults) -> UIAlertController {
    if let product = result.retrievedProducts.first {
        let priceString = product.localizedPrice!
        return alertWithTitle(title: product.localizedTitle, message: "\(product.localizedDescription) - \(priceString)")

    }
    else if let invalidProductID = result.invalidProductIDs.first {
        return alertWithTitle(title: "Could not retreive product info", message: "Invalid product identifier: \(invalidProductID)")
    }
    else {
        let errorString = result.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown Error. Please Contact Support"
        return alertWithTitle(title: "Could not retreive product info" , message: errorString)

    }

}
func alertForPurchaseResult(result : PurchaseResult) -> UIAlertController {
    switch result {
    case .success(let product):
        print("Purchase Succesful: \(product.productId)")

        return alertWithTitle(title: "Thank You", message: "Purchase completed")
    case .error(let error):
        print("Purchase Failed: \(error)")
        switch error {
        case .failed(let error):
            if (error as NSError).domain == SKErrorDomain {
                return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Failed", message: "Check your internet connection or try again later.")
            }
            else {
                return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Failed", message: "Unknown Error. Please Contact Support")
            }
        case.invalidProductId(let productID):
            return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Failed", message: "\(productID) is not a valid product identifier")
        case .noProductIdentifier:
            return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Failed", message: "Product not found")
        case .paymentNotAllowed:
            return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Failed", message: "You are not allowed to make payments")

        }
    }
}
func alertForRestorePurchases(result : RestoreResults) -> UIAlertController {
    if result.restoreFailedProducts.count > 0 {
        print("Restore Failed: \(result.restoreFailedProducts)")
        return alertWithTitle(title: "Restore Failed", message: "Unknown Error. Please Contact Support")
    }
    else if result.restoredProducts.count > 0 {
        return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchases Restored", message: "All purchases have been restored.")

    }
    else {
        return alertWithTitle(title: "Nothing To Restore", message: "No previous purchases were made.")
    }

}
func alertForVerifyReceipt(result: VerifyReceiptResult) -> UIAlertController {

    switch result {
    case.success(let receipt):
        return alertWithTitle(title: "Receipt Verified", message: "Receipt Verified Remotely")
    case .error(let error):
        switch error {
        case .noReceiptData:
            return alertWithTitle(title: "Receipt Verification", message: "No receipt data found, application will try to get a new one. Try Again.")
        default:
            return alertWithTitle(title: "Receipt verification", message: "Receipt Verification failed")
        }
    }
}
func alertForVerifySubscription(result: VerifySubscriptionResult) -> UIAlertController {
    switch result {
    case .purchased(let expiryDate):
        return alertWithTitle(title: "Product is Purchased", message: "Product is valid until \(expiryDate)")
    case .notPurchased:
        return alertWithTitle(title: "Not purchased", message: "This product has never been purchased")
    case .expired(let expiryDate):

        return alertWithTitle(title: "Product Expired", message: "Product is expired since \(expiryDate)")
    }
}
func alertForVerifyPurchase(result : VerifyPurchaseResult) -> UIAlertController {
    switch result {
    case .purchased:
        return alertWithTitle(title: "Product is Purchased", message: "Product will not expire")
    case .notPurchased:

        return alertWithTitle(title: "Product not purchased", message: "Product has never been purchased")


    }

}
func alertForRefreshRecepit(result : RefreshReceiptResult) -> UIAlertController {

    switch result {
    case .success(let receiptData):
        return alertWithTitle(title: "Receipt Refreshed", message: "Receipt refreshed successfully")
    case .error(let error):
        return alertWithTitle(title: "Receipt refresh failed", message: "Receipt refresh failed")
    }
}

}
```

Edit:
Fixed
instead of using the bundleID + "." + purchase.rawValue id I used the product Id from iTunes connect (com.KonradLoecher.inAppPurchase.UnlockPremiumVersion) I stored these ids in the enum RegisteredPurchase.

Comment: Did you find the bug?

Comment: Yes it is an easy mistake. view my edit.